# Autofac resolve by context

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

So I'm basically planning on switching from RavenDb to MongoDb and have different implementations of my repositories. I use CQRS with a message dispatcher and I would look to run my consumers twice with both sets of repos

```
       builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Consumers.IMessageConsumer<>))).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(Consumers.IMessageConsumer<>));


        builder.RegisterType<RavenUserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<MongoUserRepostiory>().As<IUserRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();


    public Task Dispatch<TMessage>(TMessage message) where TMessage : IMessage
    {

        // Raven

        using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var consumer = scope.Resolve<IMessageConsumer<TMessage>>();

            consumer.Handle(message, CancellationToken.None);
        }

        // Mongo

        using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var consumer = scope.Resolve<IMessageConsumer<TMessage>>();

            consumer.Handle(message, CancellationToken.None);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

So I basically want to tell each life time scope which repositories its allowed to use. I'm hitting a brick wall though, can't seem to work it out

Answer (score 3):

This kind of scenario is documented pretty extensively here:
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html. There are quite a few options open to you depending on your overall approach, and things like whether supporting both repos is just a short-term solution while you transition across.

An example of one of the solutions is as follows, using the `Keyed` approach. If we add a key to the repo registrations:

```
public enum RepoType
{
    Raven,
    Mongo
}

...

builder.RegisterType<RavenUserRepository>().Keyed<IUserRepository>(RepoType.Raven).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<MongoUserRepostiory>().Keyed<IUserRepository>(RepoType.Mongo).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

and instead of

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Consumers.IMessageConsumer<>))).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(Consumers.IMessageConsumer<>));
```

we have

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MessageConsumer<>))
    .Keyed(RepoType.Mongo, typeof(IMessageConsumer<>)).WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IUserRepository),
            (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IUserRepository>(RepoType.Mongo)));

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MessageConsumer<>))
    .Keyed(RepoType.Raven, typeof(IMessageConsumer<>))
    .WithParameter(
        new ResolvedParameter(
            (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IUserRepository),
            (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IUserRepository>(RepoType.Raven)));
```

That last part isn't the prettiest but for each repo it's basically saying "register an `IConsumer<>` with a key, which internally resolves using an `IUserRepository` with the same key". We can then just resolve `IConsumer<>`s as required from the consuming code, either as an `IEnumerable<>` (this is automatically available from Autofac if you have multiple registrations for a service) or individually with our key:

```
var consumers = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMessageConsumer<T>>>();
foreach (var messageConsumer in consumers)
{
    messageConsumer.Handle(message, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

or

```
var mongoConsumer = scope.ResolveKeyed<IMessageConsumer<T>>(RepoType.Mongo);
mongoConsumer.Handle(message, CancellationToken.None);

var ravenConsumer = scope.ResolveKeyed<IMessageConsumer<T>>(RepoType.Raven);
ravenConsumer.Handle(message, CancellationToken.None);
```